# visual basic <> issues

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am finding an element in an array using an input box. This is what i currently have:

```
arrayNumber = InputBox("Please enter your desired number.")
For i = 0 To 9
    If arrayNumber = data(i) Then
        outputMessage1 = ("Your number is found in the first array. " & i & " is the index of the desired number.") 
    Else
    End If
Next

For i = 0 To 9
    If arrayNumber = data2(i) Then
        outputMessage2 = ("Your number is found in the second array. " & i & " is the index of the desired number.")
    Else
    End If
Next

For i = 0 To 9
    If arrayNumber = data3(i) Then
        outputMessage3 = ("Your number is found in the third array. " & i & " is the index of the desired number.")
    Else
    End If
Next

Selection.TypeText (outputMessage1 & " " & outputMessage2 & " " & outputMessage3)

For i = 0 To 9
    If arrayNumber <> i Then
        notFound = ("Sorry the element is not found.")
    Else
    End If
Next

Selection.TypeText (notFound)
```

...

I am currently having two issues: the notFound message is popping up even if arrayNumber does equal i. How do I fix this?

Also, I know that I currently have the index of the element in each array. Is there a way I can find the earliest appearance of the element looking at all three arrays combined (i.e. if 4 is the 3rd index in the first array but the 2nd index of the second array, i want to say that the earliest appearance is in the second array).

Comment: Debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through it line by line.  As soon as the actual state differs from your expectation, you have found n issue and you can investigate that specifically.  At the very least, you can describe the details to us.  You don't fix issues with code simply by reading the code.  You run it and watch it in action.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, or at least give you an idea

```
arrayNumber = InputBox("Please enter your desired number.")
For i = 0 To 9
    If arrayNumber = data(i) Then
        outputMessage1 = ("Your number is found in the first array. " & i & " is the index of the desired number.") 

    ElseIf arrayNumber = data2(i) Then
        outputMessage2 = ("Your number is found in the second array. " & i & " is the index of the desired number.")

    ElseIf arrayNumber = data3(i) Then
        outputMessage3 = ("Your number is found in the third array. " & i & " is the index of the desired number.")
    Else
        notFound = ("Sorry the element is not found.")
    End If
Next
Selection.TypeText (outputMessage1 & " " & outputMessage2 & " " & outputMessage3)
```

If one of the `if statement` or `elseif` is triggered it will skip the other `if` or `elseif`

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly addressing the issue that "Not Found" is showing up, even if a valid number is applied.

This is the type of thing I would use as a training element for my junior developers.  Mainly because it appears to me that you have requirements that you either did not understand or were not clear and concise in their needs.

You've stated that you code is displaying the not found message, even if the provided number is a value between  0 and 9, while your code looks like this:

```
For i = 0 To 9
    If arrayNumber <> i Then
        notFound = ("Sorry the element is not found.")
    Else
    End If
Next
```

It's doing this because you're telling it to. You set NotFound whenever arrayNumber is not equal to i, but do nothing when arrayNumber is equal to i.

Regardless, you have a requirement, and a proposed logic solution, but they're not behaving as you expect. I've found that taking logic that isn't behaving as expected and shifting it into "real" words helps clarify what I'm doing.  I would translate this code into the statement of:

> For every number in my range, if the provided number (ArrayNumber) is
>   not equal to my incrementor (i) then set NotFound to "Sorry the
>   element is not found."

As always, code does what we tell it to, and this code is behaving just as written.  The thing is what you're actually trying to do is determine if a value is included in a range, while the only check you perform is that it is not included in the range. Consider this statement:

> Set NotFound to "Sorry the element is not found" when the
>   provided number (ArrayNumber) is not equal to any of the values found
>   in my range

That statement more accurately determines what you're attempting to do in the code. And while they are similar statements, the focus is shifted. At its heart the requirement is "Do X when Y is True."  But another way of looking at that type of logic, is "X, until Y is False." I've often found that requirements for data checks are often written "Do X when Y is True," but we can usually code those requirements easier (as least in my opinion) as "X, until Y is False."

That gives us the following statement:

> NotFound is set to "Sorry the element is not found" until the provided
>   number (arrayNumber) is equal to any value found in the range

To me, that style logic makes good defensive programming. It gives you a starting stance to take with the data. Which means you can either perform as per expectations, or deal with the data that fails the expectation.

Now, since we have our redefined statement of intent, we can approach the code differently.

```
notFound = ("Sorry the element is not found.")
For i = 0 To 9
    If arrayNumber = i Then 
        notFound = "" 
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

This code means that we start with the stance that the data has "failed" the included in range check, and we're validating the data to prove that stance wrong.